# Sharing folders/files with application-specific accounts

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to share a folder from my personal account with the application-specific account created by following [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts).

I have used Google Doc's share form to share the folder with my developer.gserviceaccount.com email address.

However, listing the files in the drive of this account does not show this folder.

```
public void retrieveAllFiles() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, URISyntaxException {
Drive service=getDrive();
List<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File> result = new ArrayList<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File>();
Files.List request = service.files().list();

do {
  try {
    FileList files = request.execute();

    result.addAll(files.getItems());
    request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    request.setPageToken(null);
  }
} while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
         request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

//return result;

}
```

Any suggestions?

It would be great to be able to login to Google Drive as the owner of this account.

Comment: Well, I assumed that, since I am using the application-owned account approach, I would be logging with the maximum scope (without restrictions)

Comment: In fact, I just specified DRIVE scope and nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer but I found this api test page to be helpful.
[API test page](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/drive/v2/drive.files.list?_h=1&)